# How can I change the default user shown in the login screen?

Tags: 10.10, login-screen, users

Well, the title is pretty much it.

When I start my system I always get the same user on the login screen (this is the original user created when the system was first installed). How can I change that so I won't have to type in the actual username I use everyday each time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep that is easy :

Open the GDM custom configuration file :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/gdm/custom.conf
```

Should have a lot of comment and at the end look like this :

```
[daemon]

[security]

[xdmcp]

[gui]

[greeter]

[chooser]

[debug]

[servers]
```

You'll have to add few lines under greeter like this :

```
[daemon]

[security]

[xdmcp]

[gui]

[greeter]
# If true show all the users, if false show the last connected users
IncludeAll=false
# User to always show in the user list
Include=somebody,somebodyelse

[chooser]

[debug]

[servers]
```

Just replace "somebody,somebodyelse" by whatever you want, save the file and reboot and it should work.

More info here :
http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/2.32/gdm.html

Comment: In 2021, 11 years after this answer was posted, the file to edit is now called `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Answer (score 1):

In 15.10, you can go:

- System settings
- User accounts
- Unlock (top right corner)
- Select user
- Click automatic login

This unchecks automatic login for other users, and automatically logs into that user without a password.

If you are worried about not having a password, encrypt your disk instead (will ask for a password before login screen). If an attacker gets your hardware, the login password alone will be useless (he can just mount your partition).

Comment: The current user is not listed, it broke after i removed KDE (plasma)

Answer (score 0):

Go to (gdmsetup): System -> Administration -> Login Screen

Comment: In the `login as ... automatically` it only has one option - the current default user. My user isn't there!