# How in Ubuntu 20.04 change users order on login screen

Tags: 20.04, login-screen

I have two accounts in my system. As first is showed account less often used by me. I would like to set as first on list my account. I found this topic [How can I change the order of the users in the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4324/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-the-users-in-the-login-screen) but it doesn't work.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7895/how-can-i-change-the-default-user-shown-in-the-login-screen) is old and untested by me personally. I am not sure if that method is still valid but it shouldn't hurt anything if you try it. As always, keep good backups and you'll be fine.

Comment: @KGlll  Unfortunately thinks described there doesn't exist already in Ubuntu 20.04.